# Android, storing big number of small images linked to database

Tags: android, xml, database, image

I have been asked to create a tiny android app.

In everyday work i code for .NET and I have no experience connected with Android, but as it is a really small app I guess it's going to be a good experience rather than something hard.

The core of the app would be a small database (probably `XML`, unless somebody suggest better solution) that would contain `categories`, `names of the institutions` assigned with each `category` and `logo` (not very high resolution I guess a single file would be <100kB) of the institution.

The database also would not be very big - I expect not more than 1000 records in total. The DB has to be totally offline and local, it cannot require Internet access when operating.

The model I assume would be to ship new version of the application when the database changes (which is not going to be very frequent).

What is the best way to deal with these requirements?

1. My first idea was to create an XML file that would contain the records and link to the image. The XML and all the images linked to it would be stored in single file (preferably zip) that would be stored in app resources. This is very good as it is going to be very easy to update the database.
2. The second idea that somebody suggested me would be to use `SQLite` and store images in `BLOB`. In general I have read that it isn't a good idea to store images in database directly, and I am afraid if it's going to be possible to meet all requirements mentioned above.

Mostly I have no idea how to update the database easily and attach it to new version of application.

Any suggestions?

I would be grateful for any response.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go about using `XML` to save your data and by no means zip anything.

I think your way of thinking is ok, but you're making things really complicated for yourself.

Seeing as you're used to .NET I suppose you're also pretty confident with SQL, so I'd suggest you have a look at how to use the [built-in SQLite database in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

If you would go the XML route you'd have to serialize and de-serialize the XML file over and over again and then parse the XML. Ok you don't have a lot of data, but searching inside an XML file with at least 1000 nodes would be slow in comparison to the performance of a database.

Also upgrading an existing SQLite database is not that hard - Android has methods for that (`onUpgrade` coming from the `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

As to saving images I'm assuming that you won't fetch new pictures from the Internet, so it would be best just to store them in the `drawable` folder of your app (be mindful of different screensizes) and then reading them into an `ImageView` when needed. To figure out what image should go for what institution I would store either the image name of each image in the SQLite database or store the `resource id` for each image in the database - for instance `R.drawable.myawesomepictureformyinstitution`.

I know my answer is somewhat "superficial", but your question is also somewhat "broad" and hard to answer without me actually writing most of the code, and that's not my intention ;-)

Hope this helps - let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After posting my question I have red something about SQLite and I thing that's the way to go. BUT with the way you suggested for storing files- it is impossible to store files directly into resources. I will not be the one who edits the database and for those who are going to be it's going to be a nightmare to edit resources directly. I need other way most preferably to have the database in ONE file attached to android project

Comment: @user1658223 if you think this answer solves your problem/question, please mark it as the answer :-)